# Tilde C unsigned vs signed integer

Tags: c, operators, bit-manipulation, tilde

For example:

```
unsigned int i = ~0;
```

**Result**: Max number I can assign to `i`

and

```
signed int y = ~0;
```

**Result**: `-1`

Why do I get `-1`? Shouldn't I get the maximum number that I can assign to `y`?

Comment: Are you sure you understand what the ~ operator does? (Bitwise NOT)

Comment: Well, `-1` is _the maximum_ number you can put into a an integer, but with _maximum_ defined as the absoltue binary value :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both `4294967295` (a.k.a. `UINT_MAX`) and `-1` have the same binary representation of `0xFFFFFFFF` or 32 bits all set to `1`. This is because signed numbers are represented using [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). A negative number has its MSB (most significant bit) set to `1` and its value determined by flipping the rest of the bits, adding `1` and multiplying by `-1`. So if you have the MSB set to `1` and the rest of the bits also set to `1`, you flip them (get 32 zeros), add `1` (get `1`) and multiply by `-1` to finally get `-1`.

This makes it easier for the CPU to do the math as it needs no special exceptions for negative numbers. For example, try adding `0xFFFFFFFF` (-1) and `1`. Since there is only room for 32 bits, this will overflow and the result will be `0` as expected.

See more at:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

Answer (score 5):

```
unsigned int i  = ~0;
```

> Result: Max number I can assign to i

Usually, but not necessarily. The expression `~0` evaluates to an `int` with all (non-padding) bits set. The C standard allows three representations for signed integers,

- two's complement, in which case `~0 = -1` and assigning that to an `unsigned int` results in `(-1) + (UINT_MAX + 1) = UINT_MAX`.
- ones' complement, in which case `~0` is either a negative zero or a trap representation; if it's a negative zero, the assignment to an `unsigned int` results in 0.
- sign-and-magnitude, in which case `~0` is `INT_MIN == -INT_MAX`, and assigning it to an `unsigned int` results in `(UINT_MAX + 1) - INT_MAX`, which is `1` in the unlikely case that `unsigned int` has a width (number of value bits for unsigned integer types, number of value bits + 1 [for the sign bit] for signed integer types) smaller than that of `int` and `2^(WIDTH - 1) + 1` in the common case that the width of `unsigned int` is the same as the width of `int`.

The initialisation

```
unsigned int i = ~0u;
```

will always result in `i` holding the value `UINT_MAX`.

```
signed int y = ~0;
```

> Result: -1

As stated above, only if the representation of signed integers uses two's complement (which nowadays is by far the most common representation).

Answer (score 4):

`~0` is just an `int` with all bits set to 1. When interpreted as `unsigned` this will be equivalent to `UINT_MAX`. When interpreted as `signed` this will be `-1`.

Assuming 32 bit ints:

```
 0 = 0x00000000 =  0 (signed) = 0 (unsigned)
~0 = 0xffffffff = -1 (signed) = UINT_MAX (unsigned)
```

Comment: Thank you, but why 0xffffffff is -1 in signed?

Comment: ~0 = 0xffffffff = -1 (signed, -1 in 2's complement form). Does all system follow this approach?

Comment: the assignment is not a re-interpretation, but a value conversion: `~0` when assigned to `unsigned int` will only yield `UINT_MAX` if `~0` of type `int` represents `-1`

Comment: I think it's also worth noticing how `0 - 1` is always `0xffffffff`, interpreted as `-1` if it's signed, overflowing to `UINT_MAX` if it's unsigned. And the other way, `0xffffffff + 1` is always `0`, again correct if signed, overflow from `UINT_MAX` if unsigned.

Comment: that's the benefit of having -ve numbers in 2's complement form, direct addition. Of course CPU doesn't bother about overflow etc, programmer has to.

Comment: @hyde: this is not correct - `0xffffffff` only represents `-1` if two's complement is used, whereas it represents `-2147483647` in case of sign and magnitude and `0` in ones' complement (but this might be a trap representation)

Comment: @Christoph Care to tell of a CPU implementation currently in use, for which one might actually compile C code where what I said does not hold?

Comment: @hyde: http://www.unisys.com/unisys/theme/index.jsp?id=1120000970018010225 - *always* is a pretty strong claim

Comment: Ah, you were picking on the word "always". I meant it as "both for signed and unsigned integers (in the context of the question, while making an assumption about the the computer the OP is using)". But thanks for the link, that's good to know computing trivia.

Comment: @hyde: my response was a bit of a Pavlovian reaction and ended up worded rather strongly; the underlying point is that C language semantics doesn't really care for representation, and neither should the programmer: it's the value that's relevant; `(unsigned)~0` only ends up as `UINT_MAX` if `~0==-1`, regardless of whether it is represented by `0xffffffff` or something else

Answer (score 2):

Paul's answer is absolutely right. Instead of using ~0, you can use:

```
#include <limits.h>

signed int y = INT_MAX;
unsigned int x = UINT_MAX;
```

And now if you check values:

```
printf("x = %u\ny = %d\n", UINT_MAX, INT_MAX);
```

you can see max values on your system.

Answer (score 1):

No, because `~` is the *bitwise NOT* operator, not the *maximum value for type* operator. `~0` corresponds to an `int` with all bits set to `1`, which, interpreted as an unsigned gives you the max number representable by an unsigned, and interpreted as a signed int, gives you -1.

Answer (score 0):

You must be on a [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) machine.

Comment: Brief discussion about alternative system, and how it's not used today: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement#History

Comment: The C language allows two's complement, ones' complement and sign magnitude representation, based on the underlying hardware, so it's not completely unused. If there were some hardware-based factor (speed or cost) to use one of the other representations, I bet they'd come back.

Answer (score 0):

Look up http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement, and learn a little about Boolean algebra, and logic design. Also learning how to count in binary and addition and subtraction in binary will explain this further.

The C language used this form of numbers so to find the largest number you need to use 0x7FFFFFFF. (where you use 2 FF's for each byte used and the leftmost byte is a 7.) To understand this you need to look up hexadecimal numbers and how they work.

Now to explain the unsigned equivalent. In signed numbers the bottom half of numbers are negative (0 is assumed positive so negative numbers actually count 1 higher than positive numbers). Unsigned numbers are all positive. So in theory your highest number for a 32 bit int is 2^32 except that 0 is still counted as positive so it's actually 2^32-1, now for signed numbers half those numbers are negative. which means we divide the previous number 2^32 by 2, since 32 is an exponent we get 2^31 numbers on each side 0 being positive means the range of an signed 32 bit int is (-2^31, 2^31-1).

Now just comparing ranges:
unsigned 32 bit int: (0, 2^32-1)
signed 32 bit int: (-2^31, 2^32-1)
unsigned 16 bit int: (0, 2^16-1)
signed 16 bit int: (-2^15, 2^15-1)

you should be able to see the pattern here.
to explain the ~0 thing takes a bit more, this has to do with subtraction in binary. it's just adding 1 and flipping all the bits then adding the two numbers together. C does this for you behind the scenes and so do many processors (including the x86 and x64 lines of processors.)
Because of this it's best to store negative numbers as though they are counting down, and in two's complement the added 1 is also hidden. Because 0 is assumed positive thus negative numbers can't have a value for 0, so they automatically have -1 (positive 1 after the bit flip) added to them. when decoding negative numbers we have to account for this.