# Is there a big difference between a function returning -1 and ~0?

Tags: c++, binary, twos-complement

Consider the two simple functions:

```
int return0Comp(){
    return (~0);
}

int returnNeg1(){
    return -1;
}
```

I know that on a twos-complement system, `~0==-1`, but on the off-chance that a system isn't using that (does that even happen?*), will these two functions be returning different values?

Comment: What language is this? Most have very specific semantics for what `~` does.

Comment: C/C++, updated question, thanks

Comment: They are different languages. Which do you use?

Comment: I use a c++ compiler, usually. But I wouldn't think they treat zero's compliment differently?

Comment: No they won't. So let's tag as C++.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13148205/214671

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard says [expr.unary.op.10]

> The operand of ~ shall have integral or unscoped enumeration type; the
>   result is the one’s complement of its operand.

I read this that `~` always just inverts all the bits, so the interpretation of the result should indeed depend on the representation used.